# Conversion to Standard Normal with Probability

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution, standardization

Good day everyone, I am currently working on a self-study question:

**Question**

> The number of viewers of a television show has a mean of 29 million with a standard deviation of 5 million. Assume this distribution follows a normal distribution. What is the probability that at least one of the four shows has more than 36 million viewers in the next four shows. Assume the number of viewers in each show are independent.

**My Attempt**

> [image]

However, it seemed that the answer is not correct from that of the answer key (0.2861). Appreciate some guidance on this. I know I'm missing out on something, but I just can't figure out what.

Comment: You don't seem to be dealing with the "at least one of the four" part. You deal with that part using basic probability calculations.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Glen. I attempted to take (0.0808)^4 but to no avail either. Guess it is not as simple as this. I was wondering if Binomial is something that can be used here? With success means having more than 36 million viewers, and failure otherwise. Many thanks once again.

Comment: Looks like I've managed to get the answer using Binomial. Many thanks for the advice Glen. I will post my solution shortly

Answer (score 1):

> [image]

After taking in Glen's advice that I am missing the "at least one of four" part on the question, I managed to use the Binomial function to solve the equation.

What I did was to count an instance of having more than 36 million viewers as a success, and failure otherwise.

Using the Binomial function: $P(X=k) = C_n^k \cdot p^k \cdot (1 - p)^{n-k}$

To find $P(Y>0)$, we can compute $1 - P(Y=0)$.

Therefore, 
\begin{align*}
P(Y > 0) 
 &= 1 - P(Y=0) \\
 &= 1 - C_4^0 \cdot 0.0808^0 \cdot (1 - 0.0808)^4 \\
 &= 0.286096.
\end{align*}